# How to access index value in `pd.Series` aggregation or mapping?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After a `groupby` operation, I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex (say, level names are `i1`, `i2`).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "i1": list("abcde"),
        "i2": range(10, 20, 2),
        "c1": range(1, 11, 2),
        "c2": list("fghij"),
    }
).set_index(["i1", "i2"])

print(df)
```

```
       c1 c2
i1 i2       
a  10   1  f
b  12   3  g
c  14   5  h
d  16   7  i
e  18   9  j
```

I would like to update the column `c1` according to a condition based on both `i1` and `c2`.
I think of something like:

```py
def _agg(row) -> float:
    # See "Edit 1" for more details
    return my_custom_function(row["c2"], row["i1"])

df["c1"] += df.agg(_agg, axis="columns")
```

However, this raises an exception because "i1" is not available.

```
KeyError: 'i1'
```

I tried with `reset_index` but this raises another exception because you cannot sum two series with non-overlapping index:

```
df["c1"] += df.reset_index().agg(_agg, axis="columns")
```

```
ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names
```

Kind,
Alexis

---

## Edit 1

In my first example, I use only numeric columns and my aggregation function was a "simple" numeric operation:

```py
def _agg(row):
    return row["c2"] * (row["i1"] % 4)
```

For such kind of computation, we can avoid the `df.agg` call as suggested by [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78064304/4373898) of [@Andrej Kesely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely). This is a valid answer but is not applicable to my use case.

I tried to craft a more representative aggregation function something like this, with more weird conditionals and some "side-effects" (accessing environment variables or something similar):

```py
def _agg(row) -> float:
    import os

    if str(row["c2"]).startswith("f"):
        return float(os.environ.get(str(row["i1"]).upper(), -1))
    elif not str(row["c2"]).startswith("j"):
        return float(os.environ.get(f"MY_VAR_{str(row['i1']).upper()}", 0))
    else:
        return 1
```

I don't think that a solution based on accessing the level values through `df.index.get_level_values` can be applied for such case.

## Edit 2

One of my untold idea was to conserve the index (because my dataset can be large and having an index sounds good, as well as it makes sure that the right rows are summed).

I looked for a method, similar to `reset_index(level="i1")`, which add the `i1` column to the dataset, but keep it in the index too !

This doesn't seem to exist. Is `df.assign({"i1": df.index.get_level_values("i1")})` an acceptable workaround (what is the cost of adding such column) ?

Comment: `"l1"` or `"I1"` ? Very often, an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) speaks *louder* than words.

Comment: @Timeless sorry, writing a good example on smartphone is hard ;-). I updated the question with a complete MWE. Hope it will help to understand.

Comment: No worries ;) In your 2nd approach, have you tried adding `.to_numpy()` to avoid *index-alignment* ?

Comment: @Timeless I didn't try this. It seems to work, thanks for the workaround. However, is it a "good idea" to lose the overall index-alignment process ? This is a way to ensure that the right rows sum together.

Answer (score 2):

You can access index level values with [`df.index.get_level_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html#pandas-index-get-level-values):

```py
df["c1"] += df.index.get_level_values("i1") % 4 * df["c2"]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       c1  c2
i1 i2        
0  10   1  11
2  12  29  13
4  14   5  15
6  16  41  17
8  18   9  19
```

---

EDIT: New version based on your example:

```py
import os

def get_val(i1, c2):
    if c2.startswith("f"):
        return os.environ.get(i1.upper(), -1)
    elif not c2.startswith("j"):
        return os.environ.get(f"MY_VAR_{i1.upper()}", 0)
    else:
        return 1


df["c1"] += [get_val(i1, c2) for i1, c2 in zip(df.index.get_level_values("i1"), df.c2)]
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my real use case, the "aggregation" function is more complicated than a simple numeric operation, so you're solution is not applicable. I am going to update the example to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't think about zipping two pd.Series ! I suppose that this is similar to the solution proposed by @Timeless (resetting the index and then calling `.to_numpy()`) as you lost the index-alignment feature.